# OrientDB null pointer exception while graph.shutdown & GC Overhead limit exceeded

Tags: nullpointerexception, garbage-collection, orientdb, overhead

I'm using OrientDB 2.2.20 on PROD env with latest jdk1.8. We just upgraded ODB to 2.2.20 yesterday and it doesnot seems to stable. We are getting following exception

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.makeActive(OrientBaseGraph.java:362)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.shutdown(OrientBaseGraph.java:1145)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.shutdown(OrientBaseGraph.java:1138)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.shutdown(OrientBaseGraph.java:1131)
```

And just to report this error OrientDB took 30+ mins

Apart from above exception i'm also getting `GC Overhead limit exceeded error` which requires us to restart the DB 3-4 times in a days.

Following are the config on PROD.

```
/bin/java -server -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Drhino.opt.level=9 -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=26624 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-log.properties -Dorientdb.config.file=/opt/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml -Dorientdb.www.path=/opt/orientdb/www -Dorientdb.build.number=2.2.x@r76ab59e72943d0ba196188ed100c882be4315139; 2017-05-11 13:55:56+0000 -cp /opt/orientdb/lib/orientdb-server-2.2.20.jar:/opt/orientdb/lib/*:/opt/orientdb/plugins/* com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain
```

Let me know what else you would need to debug this issue.

Comment: 2.2.24 was released yesterday. Can you try with the latest version?  A lot of bugs were solved in the last months.

Comment: I got the same reply last month when our ODB version was 2.1.16 and that was also unstable so we upgraded to 2.2.20, now though it was upgraded ODB is still not stable and our systems are completely useless without the backend DB. We will try to upgrade to the latest one what is a guarantee that even that version is going to work.

Comment: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7576

Comment: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/7577
I have logged these 2 bugs on OrientDB Git site. 
Would anybody try to debug them confirm if they are already got fixed in 2.2.24?